# Does type aliasing issue exist only when pointers are passed to functions as arguments?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, type-alias

As far as I know, when two pointers (or references) do not type alias each other, it is legal to for the compiler to make the assumption that they address different locations and to make certain optimizations thereof, e.g., reordering instructions. Therefore, having pointers to different types to have the same value may be problematic. However, I think this issue only applies when the two pointers are passed to functions. Within the function body where the two pointers are created, the compiler should be able to make sure the relationship between them as to whether they address the same location. Am I right?

Comment: Umm... If you pass a pointer to a struct, and a pointer to the first member of that struct, those pointers are essentially aliasing, even though they are pointers to different types...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I know, when two pointers (or references) do not type alias
>   each other, it is legal to for the compiler to make the assumption
>   that they address different locations and to make certain
>   optimizations thereof, e.g., reordering instructions.

Correct. GCC, for example, does perform optimizations of this form which can be disabled by passing the flag `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

> However, I think this issue only applies when the two pointers are
>   passed to functions. Within the function body where the two pointers
>   are created, the compiler should be able to make sure the relationship
>   between them as to whether they address the same location. Am I right?

The standard doesn't distinguish between where those pointers came from. If your operation has undefined behavior, the program has undefined behavior, period. The compiler is in no way obliged to analyze the operands at compile time, but he may give you a warning.

Answer (score -1):

Implementations which are designed and intended to be suitable for low-level programming should have no particular difficulty recognizing common patterns where storage of one type is reused or reinterpreted as another in situations not involving aliasing, provided that:

1. Within any particular function or loop, all pointers or lvalues used to access a particular piece of storage are derived from lvalues of a common type which identify the same object or elements of the same array, and
2. Between the creation of a derived-type pointer and the last use of it or any pointer derived from it, all operations involving the storage are performed only using the derived pointer or other pointers derived from it.

Most low-level programming scenarios requiring reuse or reinterpretation of storage fit these criteria, and handling code that fits these criteria will typically be rather straightforward in an implementation designed for low-level programming.  If an implementation cache lvalues in registers and performs loop hoisting, for example, it could support the above semantics reasonably efficiently by flushing all cached values of type T whenever T or T* is used to form a pointer or lvalue of another type.  Such an approach may be optimal, but would degrade performance much less than having to block all type-based optimizations entirely.

Note that it is probably in many cases not worthwhile for even an implementation intended for low-level programming to try to handle all possible scenarios involving aliasing.  Doing that would be much more expensive than handling the far more common scenarios that don't involve aliasing.

Implementations which are specialized for other purposes are, of course, not required to make any attempt whatsoever to support any exceptions to 6.5p7--not even those that are often treated as part of the Standard.  Whether such an implementation should be able to support such constructs would depend upon the particular purposes for which it is designed.